# Does React Native currently support accessing a user's Address Book

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

It does not look like the core React Native APIs has anything listed for  Address Book on iOS.  This seems like a core thing you would need to do in an app.

Is this something that just needs to be built, or is there a particular reason there seems to be no info on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have begun work on a Native Module that supports reading from a users contacts, once granted permission.

[react-native-addressbook-ios](https://github.com/mattotodd/react-native-addressbook-ios)

Comment: Thanks for getting started on this. We aren't working on this yet at FB, so I'm glad you jumped in!

Answer (score 2):

I just don't think it's been addressed yet, and there's not even anything in the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues). The RN team do seem to have some things internally at Facebook that still haven't been made public, so we might see it from them in the future but the best way to find out would be to create a new issue to track any work on a Contacts API. I've [done that for you here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/686). 
vjeux has already replied with his thoughts.